# Unwanted Space next to main content on website

Tags: html, css

So next to the main content (outside of the browser width) if you scroll to the left of the page there is extra space occupied by only the background of the Body CSS background. Here's the site in action http://test.crows-perch.com/.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    z-index: 0;
    background: url(../images/background-texture%20d.jpg);
    width: 100%;
}
#page {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#Footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 230px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
#TopLinks {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: 37px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000000;
    background: url(../images/background-texture-b.jpg);
}
#Links {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 329px;
    text-align: center;
}
#Links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7F7F7F;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#Links a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#HeaderContainer {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(../images/tri-button%20texture%20b.jpg);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #7F7F7F;
}
#title {
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
    width: 252px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -10px;
    right: 383px;
}
#Home {
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
    width: 96px;
    height: 65px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 204px;
    top: -70px;
    background: url(../images/button%20texture%20b.jpg);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #7F7F7F;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#Home:hover {
    width: 96px;
    background: url(../images/button%20overlay%20b.png) no-repeat center, url(../images/button%20texture%20b.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: cover;
}
#HomeT {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Cinzel Regular";
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #D2C300;
    line-height: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a.Home {
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 65px;
}
#Guides {
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -135px;
    right: 89px;
    width: 133px;
    height: 65px;
    background: url(../images/button%20texture%20b.jpg);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #7F7F7F;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#Guides:hover {
    width: 133px;
    background: url(../images/button%20overlay%20b.png) no-repeat center, url(../images/button%20texture%20b.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: cover;
}
#GuidesT {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Cinzel Regular";
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #D2C300;
    line-height: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a.Guides {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#Forum {
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -200px;
    left: 33px;
    width: 114px;
    height: 65px;
    background: url(../images/button%20texture%20b.jpg);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #7F7F7F;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#Forum:hover {
    width: 114px;
    background: url(../images/button%20overlay%20b.png) no-repeat center, url(../images/button%20texture%20b.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: cover;
}
#ForumT {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Cinzel Regular";
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #D2C300;
    line-height: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a.Forum {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#Blog {
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -265px;
    left: 141px;
    width: 102px;
    height: 65px;
    background: url(../images/button%20texture%20b.jpg);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #7F7F7F;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#Blog:hover {
    width: 102px;
    background: url(../images/button%20overlay%20b.png) no-repeat center, url(../images/button%20texture%20b.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: cover;
}
#BlogT {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Cinzel Regular";
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #D2C300;
    line-height: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a.Blog {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#Guilds {
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -330px;
    left: 262px;
    width: 138px;
    height: 65px;
    background: url(../images/button%20texture%20b.jpg);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #7F7F7F;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#Guilds:hover {
    width: 138px;
    background: url(../images/button%20overlay%20b.png) no-repeat center, url(../images/button%20texture%20b.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: cover;
}
#GuildsT {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Cinzel Regular";
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #D2C300;
    line-height: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a.Guilds {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#Play {
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 168px;
    height: 65px;
    top: -395px;
    left: 415px;
    background: url(../images/button%20texture%20bright.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #7F7F7F;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#Play:hover {
    width: 168px;
    background: url(../images/button%20overlay%20c.png) no-repeat center, url(../images/button%20texture%20bright.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: cover;
}
#PlayT {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Cinzel Bold";
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 64px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a.Play {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#Top-Gradient {
    z-index: 6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(../images/gradient.png) repeat-x;
}
#PictureContainer-top {
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    left: -2px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 423px;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(../images/fire%20bg%20art.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#G1 {
    z-index: 6;
    width: 1037px;
    height: 19px;
    left: -19px;
    top: 194px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
 filter: alpha(opacity=50) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#FF000000, GradientType=0);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#FF000000', GradientType=0)";
    border-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
}
#ContentTop {
    z-index: 6;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(../images/tri-button%20texture.jpg) repeat-x center top;
    width: 1037px;
    height: 49px;
    left: -19px;
    top: 173px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px -1px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px #000000;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
}
#SwordL {
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    margin-left: 9px;
}
#TeamUp {
    z-index: 6;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -23px;
    left: 96px
}
#SwordR {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: -9px;
}
#G2 {
    z-index: 6;
    width: 1039px;
    height: 19px;
    top: -60px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#FF000000, GradientType=0);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#FF000000', GradientType=0)";
    border-color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#ContentAfterTop {
    z-index: 9;
    width: 1011px;
    height: 35px;
    top: -60px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 43px -1px #000000;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 43px #000000;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/tri-button%20texture.jpg) repeat left top;
}
#G3 {
    z-index: 5;
    width: 267px;
    height: 19px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: -633px;
    top: 120px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
 filter: alpha(opacity=50) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#FF000000, GradientType=0);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#FF000000', GradientType=0)";
    border-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transform: matrix(0, -1, 1, 0, 124, 143);
    -ms-transform: matrix(0, -1, 1, 0, 124, 143);
    -o-transform: matrix(0, -1, 1, 0, 124, 143);
    transform: matrix(0, -1, 1, 0, 124, 143);
}
#G3-2 {
    z-index: 5;
    width: 269px;
    height: 19px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    left: 730px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
 filter: alpha(opacity=50) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#FF000000, GradientType=0);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#FF000000', GradientType=0)";
    border-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transform: matrix(0, 1, -1, 0, 144, -125);
    -ms-transform: matrix(0, 1, -1, 0, 144, -125);
    -o-transform: matrix(0, 1, -1, 0, 144, -125);
    transform: matrix(0, 1, -1, 0, 144, -125);
    position: relative;
}
#AfterPicBreak {
    z-index: 6;
    height: 240px;
    border-color: #000000;
    background: url(../images/bg%20texture%20top.jpg) repeat-x left top;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 485px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
#G4 {
    z-index: 5;
    height: 92px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 430px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#FF000000, GradientType=0);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#FF000000', GradientType=0)";
    border-color: #000000;
}
#G5 {
    z-index: 6;
    width: 999px;
    height: 19px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 999px;
    top: -247px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#FF000000, GradientType=0);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#FF000000', GradientType=0)";
    border-color: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 999, 19);
    -ms-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 999, 19);
    -o-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 999, 19);
    transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 999, 19);
}
#ContentBreak {
    z-index: 5;
    background: url(../images/break%20-%20large.jpg) repeat-x left top;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: -260px;
    width: 999px;
    height: 61px;
}
#Content {
    z-index: 7;
    background: url(../images/content%20bg.jpg) repeat left top;
    position: relative;
    top: -268px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 999px;
    height: 88px;
    padding-bottom: 700px;
}
#G6 {
    z-index: 8;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -1078px;
    left: -997px;
    width: 996px;
    height: 19px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#FF000000, GradientType=0);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#FF000000', GradientType=0)";
    border-color: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 996, 19);
    -ms-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 996, 19);
    -o-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 996, 19);
    transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 996, 19);
}
#LinkText {
    z-index: 7;
    position: relative;
    top: -1040px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#LinkText a {
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #D2C300;
    font-family: "Cinzel Regular";
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#ContentSmallBreak {
    z-index: 7;
    background: url(../images/small%20break.jpg) repeat-x left top;
    width: 999px;
    height: 34px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -1010px;
}
#BottomG {
    z-index: 6;
    background: url(../images/bg%20texture%20bottom.jpg) repeat-x center bottom;
    width: 100%;
    height: 247px;
    position: relative;
    top: -140px;
    left: 0px;
}
#G7 {
    z-index: 10;
    height: 19px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: -156px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, #000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#FF000000, GradientType=0);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#FF000000', GradientType=0)";
    border-color: #000000;
}
#FooterBreak {
    z-index: 8;
    background: url(../images/break%20-%20large.jpg) repeat-x left top;
    height: 54px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: -158px;
    width: 100%;
}
#FooterBG {
    z-index: 6;
    background: url(../images/parchment.jpg) repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 149px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: -158px;
}
#FooterBreak2 {
    z-index: 12;
    background: url(../images/FooterBreak.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 11px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: -158px;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cinzel Regular';
    src: url('../fonts/cinzel-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/cinzel-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/cinzel-regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cinzel Bold';
    src: url('../fonts/cinzel-regular-bold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/cinzel-regular-bold.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/cinzel-regular-bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Use the Chrome or Firefox Developer Tools to inspect how the browser turned your CSS into a rendering. Start with the empty page first, add the remaining elements step by step and you will see what breaks it. I have the feeling that the over-use of absolute and relative positioning is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for this is the `div` with the ID `Links`. By default, is has a 100% width. Then you push it to the right by 329px (using `left: 329px`). These 329px are the amount of unwanted space you get.

Instead, you’ll probably want to do something like this:

```css
#Links {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 1011px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You’ll then still have two additional pixels. These are caused by the borders of `#TopLinks` and `#HeaderContainer`. You can fix this by either setting `box-sizing: border-box` or by getting rid of the 100% width and setting `right: 0` instead.

Comment: You can also use overflow-x: hidden; on your body tag to remove scroll left / right.

Comment: @AnthonyCarbon Not a good idea. This just hides the scrollbar. The area will still be reachable using drag & drop or touch events. Instead of fighting the symptoms, it’s better to identify the underlying cause.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any space to the left of the content, the space to the right is caused by the way you position elements: if you shift block elements to the right setting `left` property, they keep their width and need some space outside of the screen. You need to either set the width manually or change their `display` property to`inline-block` (start with `#Links`, you'll see what I'm talking about).